# Serving multiple websocket clients from a reverse-proxy nginx server

Tags: javascript, python, nginx, websocket, server

I have an nginx instance that reverse-proxies a websocket to protect an internal python app that runs a websocket server. I want multiple javascript clients to connect to the nginx server and the python app to handle the multiple clients. Currently, when one javascript client closes its websocket connection, all of the websocket clients die as well. I'd like the python app to be able to maintain a separate connection for each client. I'm using the websockets library for python. (https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

nginx server config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  192.168.1.196;

    location / {
        root /export/fs/opt/a5/web/static;
        index index.html index.htm;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8889;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

javascript:

```
var my_socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + ":80/socket.io/");

my_socket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log("websocket opened");
};
```

python:

```
def start_websocket_server():
    ip_address = "127.0.0.1"

    web_sock = websockets.serve(handler, ip_address, 8889)
    asyncio.ensure_future(web_sock)
    print('websocket server created on ' + ip_address)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by modifying the websockets library to add a max connections parameter. Then, any time a client disconnects, since there's only one websocket that handles multiple sessions from the clients, I only disconnect the socket if there's no more active sessions.